# Quicksort using one method

Tags: java

My professor asked me to sort an array of integers using the quicksort algorithm but without the optimization of using methods. He stated that the program must be contained on one method. My question is, is it possible? If so can any of you demonstrate because he only taught us about the bubble sort algorithm.

Comment: You can simulate recursion using loops and an array to hold the simulated call stack.   Therefore it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in a single method. The whole recursion can be done iteratively by using loops and stacks. So the quick sort algorithm can rewritten as this:

```
public class Main {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Func {
        void call(int[] arr, int i, int j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {45, 123, 12, 3, 656, 32};
        System.out.println("Unsorted array: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        // store swap function as a lambda to avoid code duplication
        Func swap = (int[] arr, int i, int j) -> {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        };

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(0);
        stack.push(numbers.length);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int end = stack.pop();
            int start = stack.pop();
            if (end - start < 2) {
                continue;
            }

            // partitioning part
            int position = start + ((end - start) / 2);
            int low = start;
            int high = end - 2;
            int piv = numbers[position];
            swap.call(numbers, position, end - 1);
            while (low < high) {
                if (numbers[low] < piv) {
                    low++;
                } else if (numbers[high] >= piv) {
                    high--;
                } else {
                    swap.call(numbers, low, high);
                }
            }
            position = high;
            if (numbers[high] < piv) {
                position++;
            }
            swap.call(numbers, end - 1, position);
            // end partitioning part

            stack.push(position + 1);
            stack.push(end);
            stack.push(start);
            stack.push(position);
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```